# Problem with Update Manager: E:Type '/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu' is not known on line 3 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/tualatrix-ppa-natty.list

Tags: update-manager

When I start the Update Manager it shows me this message:

> Could not initialize the package information
>   An unresolvable problem occurred while initializing the package information.
>   Please report this bug against the 'update-manager' package and include the following error message:
>
> ```
> 'E:Type '/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu' is not known on line 3 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/tualatrix-ppa-natty.list"
> ```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you post the contents of /etc/apt/sources.list.d/tualatrix-ppa-natty.list?

Answer (score 3):

try these commands...

```
sudo rm  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/tualatrix-ppa-natty.list
sudo apt-add-repository  ppa:tualatrix/ppa
```

i have tested this repository now, it works here, maybe you have some error in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/tualatrix-ppa-natty.list